# Save Unique Representation of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, sha

In my application, I need to compare vcards and figure out if there are changes between them.

I don't want to keep in memory a whole vcard, since this could be quite massive. What I would like to do is to keep a hashed value of that vcard, but the hash value has to be very precise as to not repeat itself in cases of very close/similar vcards (e.g. where differences are by a character).

I have tried Objective-C's `hash` method for strings, but that doesn't really work well, as it will create duplicates in case of similar vcards.

I am now thinking of using SHA256 to encrypt the vcards and then compare the SHA's (similar to how one would do password comparison).

Would that be a good idea? Any other ideas of how I can save a smaller version of a big string and then be able to compare it with another one for changes?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but can't you just save these big strings to file, and read them in and compare them with one of NSString's compare methods?

Comment: @mark, I have thought of that, but I figured these vcards can be quite massive, so would take up too much space if they are too many (1000+)

Comment: What if you read in the vcards from file line by line to compare so only a small portion of each vcard is in memory at any given moment. That you don't eat up too much memory. This might be slow but I think it would work.